# 1px appears on specifics cases, i can't understand why

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have reproduce the same template than my code but i can't reproduce the same bug on JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/V9BDR/1/

Here is what happen:

There is a space (about 1px) which appears between the`<img>` and the `border-right` of the `<div id="page">` (the red border right) in the whole vertical ligne (for all the childs of `<div id="page">`) when:

- There is an overflow on axe Y.
- There is a red `border-left-width` between 3px and 6px, 10px and 13px, 17px and 20px...

I really don't understand, especially the fact the this pixel disapears when the red border left (i also can find patterns with the right border width which erase this mysterious pixel) is between some regular intervals.

I could change my borders from 5px to 6px, this is a case this pixel desapears, but i realley would like to understand what is not "stable" in my code.

Maybe these symptoms talk to you ! I am sorry i am not able to reproduce it on jsFiddle

**UPDATE:**

Here is a screenshot of what happens precisely when i resize the window to a smartphone resolution (i used a simple white picture for the `<img> src`).

If i return to a desktop resolution, i just have 1px between the image and the black border (for each different width window value, the image is like floating around):

[image: bug]

We can see that the picture go over the border even if its `<div>` parent (currently selected in the console) is well fitted. it's like the image would be on `absolute position`, but it's well `inline-block` (with a simple `text-align: right` apply on its parent).

Comment: You mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/V9BDR/show/

Comment: This happens because you have set `text-align: center;` on `#menu` class, an then streched `img` inside of it. If you set `text-align: right;` on `#menu`, problem will dissappear. Or you can just add `min-width: 100%;` on `img` and remove fixed width.

Comment: @Musa yes exactly but with just 1px

Comment: @MiljanPuzović It doesn't fix the issue, this is not just in the menu, the whole right side has a 1px vertical lign since the div `#page`

Comment: Ok, then I can't reproduce that problem, sorry.